# incrementing the index of a list element Haskell

Tags: haskell

With my function fun, I'd like to get an output such as this:

```
[ ("fluffy", "loves", "bunny"), ("monkey", "feeds", "fluffy"), 
  ("bunny", "feeds", "monkey") ]
```

currently my output is this:

```
[("fluffy","eats","bunny"),("fluffy","eats","monkey"),("fluffy","feeds","bunny")]
```

my problem is that the first name is the same every time, and i want it to be different so tried to use indexing: (u1 !! n+1 /= u2) 
However this gives me an error when i try to run it:

```
   Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the second argument of ‘(/=)’, namely ‘u2’
    In the expression: u1 !! n + 1 /= u2
```

my code:

```
names = ["fluffy", "bunny", "monkey"]
n= 0
fun = [ (u1, v, u2) | u1 <- names, v <- ["eats", "feeds", "loves"], u2 <- names, u1 /= u2]
funThree = take 3 (cycle fun)
```

Can anyone tell me how i can fix this? Thank you

Comment: What happens if you remove the `u1 !! n + 1 /= u2` part from you comprehension and look at just `fun` instead of `funThree`?  Also, your type error comes in because `u1` and `u1` are both `String`, which is an alias for `[Char]`.  When you index it with `n+1`, you're getting a specific character out of the string then trying to compare it to another string.  Haskell doesn't let you use `/=` to compare a character and a string, so it shows a type error.

Comment: Instead of indexing, you could check if `u1 /= u2` instead.  Would that help?

Comment: `u1` is a `String`, so when you index it, you get a `Char`, while `u2` is still a `String`.

Comment: @bheklilr u1 /= u2 is what i have currently which does not give me the desire output

Comment: @JustinWood any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @Chalupa What conditions determine the output you want above?  It seems that there's no correlation between the verbs and the names, you just want a particular order to them.  Is it that you want to `zip (cycle names) (drop 1 $ cycle names)` to get the correct name order?  How do you actually want to choose which verbs go where?  Keep in mind that doing `[(x, y) | x <- list1, y <- list2]` is essentially a cartesian product of those two lists.  Is this what you want?  Are you sure that list comprehensions are the way to go?

Comment: Please don't edit fixes silently into your question's code, it makes the question now look meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you produce a list of name pairs from your names list.

```
namePairs names = zip cnames (drop 1 cnames) -- modify number as desired
    where cnames = cycle names
```

which produces the pairs (fluffy, bunny), (bunny, monkey), etc.

Then your function essentially becomes a zipWith where you add the action.

Or you could start out with a zip3 in the first place, combining names, actions and sublist of the cycled names.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space of possible sentences that is 3 by 3 by 3, with 9 of the sentences crossed off by `u1 /= u2`.

```
        eats                    feeds                   loves                  <- v
       |fluffy|bunny |monkey|  |fluffy|bunny |monkey|  |fluffy|bunny |monkey|  <- u2
-------|------|------|------|  |------|------|------|  |------|------|------|
       |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |
fluffy |  X   |      |      |  |  X   |      |      |  |  X   |      |      |
       |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |
-------|------|------|------|  |------|------|------|  |------|------|------|
       |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |
bunny  |      |  X   |      |  |      |  X   |      |  |      |  X   |      |
       |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |
-------|------|------|------|  |------|------|------|  |------|------|------|
       |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |
monkey |      |      |  X   |  |      |      |  X   |  |      |      |  X   |
       |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |  |      |      |      |
-----------------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
^u1
```

You need to decide what order to visit these in. List comprehensions treat the first source list as the outermost list and the last one as the innermost list. They run across the last list completely before taking a single step in the second to last list, then run across the last list completely again before taking a second step in the second to last list. A step in the first list isn't made until all of the combinations from the later lists are explored. This is the same as reading the above table left to right and top to bottom like you would read a book.

You can change the order of the results from a list comprehension by changing the order of the source lists. There are 6 possible orders of the source lists.

If none of these give you what you want, you'll need to figure out how to describe the order you want to visit the points in sentence space, either to tell the compiler or tell someone else to ask for help. Try numbering the boxes (including the `X`ed out ones) with the numbers from `1` to `27` to specify the order and look for a pattern. There are over 6 quadrillion possible orders for just the 18 possible sentences.